# Reactstrap - Carousel caption to right of image

Tags: reactjs, carousel, reactstrap

I am trying to make the caption for my Reactstrap carousel to appear to the right of the image but still in the carousel. At present, the test is appearing over the image like in the example provided in the documentation.

My JS:

```
render() {
  const { activeIndex } = this.state;

  const slides = items.map((item) => {
    return (
      <CarouselItem
        onExiting={this.onExiting}
        onExited={this.onExited}
        key={item.src}
      >

        <div className='ImgCont'>
          <img width='100%' src={item.src} alt={item.altText} />
        </div>
        <div className='TextCont'>
          <CarouselCaption captionHeader={item.header}  captionText={item.caption}  />
        </div>
      </CarouselItem>
    );
  });

render() {
  <div className='TrustedMechs'>
    <Carousel
      className='trustedMechCarousel'
      activeIndex={activeIndex}
      next={this.next}
      previous={this.previous}
    >
    <CarouselIndicators items={items} activeIndex={activeIndex} onClickHandler={this.goToIndex} />
    {slides}
    <CarouselControl direction="prev" directionText="Previous" onClickHandler={this.previous} />
    <CarouselControl direction="next" directionText="Next" onClickHandler={this.next} />
    </Carousel>
  </div>
});
```

My CSS:

```
.TrustedMechs{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 4%;
  width: 100%;
}

.trustedMechCarousel{
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.ImgCont{
  float: left !important;
}

.TextCont{
  float: right !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. My code is as follows:

JavaScript:

```
import {
  Carousel,
  CarouselItem,
  CarouselControl,
  CarouselIndicators,
  CarouselCaption } from 'reactstrap';

const items = [
  {
     src: ./path/to/image,
     altText: 'Image alt Text',
     header: 'Heading',
     caption: 'Content here'
  },
  {
     src: ./path/to/image,
     altText: 'Image alt Text',
     header: 'Heading',
     caption: 'Content here'
  },
  {
     src: ./path/to/image,
     altText: 'Image alt Text',
     header: 'Heading',
     caption: 'Content here'
  }
];

class CarouselExample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    activeIndex: 0,
  };

  this.next = this.next.bind(this);
  this.previous = this.previous.bind(this);
  this.goToIndex = this.goToIndex.bind(this);
  this.onExiting = this.onExiting.bind(this);
  this.onExited = this.onExited.bind(this);

}


  onExiting() {
    this.animating = true;
  }

  onExited() {
    this.animating = false;
  }

  next() {
    if (this.animating) return;
    const nextIndex = this.state.activeIndex === items.length - 1 ? 0 : 
    this.state.activeIndex + 1;
    this.setState({ activeIndex: nextIndex });
  }

  previous() {
    if (this.animating) return;
    const nextIndex = this.state.activeIndex === 0 ? items.length - 1 : 
    this.state.activeIndex - 1;
    this.setState({ activeIndex: nextIndex });
  }

  goToIndex(newIndex) {
    if (this.animating) return;
    this.setState({ activeIndex: newIndex });
  }

  render() {

    const { activeIndex } = this.state;
    const slides = items.map((item) => {

    return (
      <CarouselItem
        onExiting={this.onExiting}
        onExited={this.onExited}
        key={item.src}
      >

        <div className='carouselCont'>
          <div className='ImgCont'>
            <img width='100%' src={item.src} alt={item.altText} />
          </div>
          <div className='TextCont'>
            <CarouselCaption captionHeader={item.header}  captionText={item.caption}  />
          </div>
        </div>
      </CarouselItem>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <Carousel className='trustedMechCarousel' activeIndex={activeIndex} next={this.next} previous={this.previous}>
          <CarouselIndicators items={items} activeIndex={activeIndex} onClickHandler={this.goToIndex} />
          {slides}
          <CarouselControl direction="prev" directionText="Previous" onClickHandler={this.previous} />
          <CarouselControl direction="next" directionText="Next" onClickHandler={this.next} />
        </Carousel>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CarouselExample ;
```

The CSS is as follows:

```
.trustedMechCarousel{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.carouselCont{
  background-color: #f1f2ed;
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: row !important;
  align-items: center;
}

.ImgCont{
  float: left !important;
  width: 50%;
}

.TextCont{
  padding: 1% !important;
  position: relative;
  height: 50%;
  right: 4%;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.carousel-caption{
  position: relative !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  width: 75% !important;
}

.TextCont p{
  color: black !important;
}

.TextCont h3{
  color: black !important;
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon,
.carousel-control-next-icon {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  outline: black;
  background-size: 100%, 100%;
  background-image: none;
}

.carousel-control-next-icon:after{
  content: '>';
  font-size: 55px;
  color: black;
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon:after {
  content: '<';
  font-size: 55px;
  color: white;
}
```

This is for my carousel. The custom control icons were used because the default ones were getting in the way of text.